# Kendo UI access separately 2 array Json

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a json that is returned from MVC controller as 2 arrays of data (1st - object, 2nd - primitive type string).

```
public ActionResult CategoriesChartFilteredData(string[] brands)
{
    List<CategoryData> categoryData = getCategoryData();
    List<string> brandNames = getBrandNames();
    return Json( new { allBrandNames = brandNames, categoriesData = categoryData }
            , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I thought I would access the individual arrays(or properties - here these are brandNames and categoryData) via dot notation in `data-bind: "source: ..."`, but it's not working. I tried with [0] as well, which I found somewhere, but not sure If I use this right. I'm wrapping my head around it, while it's probably something very basic, but I cannot trace a good example in docs or online.

```
<div id="container">
    <select multiple="multiple" data-role="multiselect"
        data-bind="source: dataComparisons.allBrandNames"></select>

    <div data-role="chart" data-bind="source: dataComparisons.categoriesData" 
    data-series-defaults="{type: 'column'}" data-series="[{field: 'Coverage'}]"></div> 
</div>
```

I'm using viewmodel as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var viewModel = kendo.observable({
        autoSync: true,
        dataComparisons: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/dashboard/categoriesChartFilteredData",
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            },
        })
    });

    kendo.bind($("#container"), viewModel);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kendo.data.DataSource` is not designed to handle multiple data arrays. Split it in separate requests or make custom manual ajax request and then fill `viewModel`

**Update**

1.Separate datasources (two separate mvc actions `categoriesData` and `brandNames` and binddings `data-bind="source: categoriesData` and `data-bind="source: brandNames`):

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    autoSync: true,
    categoriesData: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/dashboard/categoriesData",
                dataType: "json"
            }
        },
    }),
    brandNames: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/dashboard/brandNames",
                dataType: "json"
            }
        },
    })
});
```

2.External ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'post', //or 'get'
    url:'/dashboard/categoriesChartFilteredData',
    success:function(data){
        var viewModel = kendo.observable({
            autoSync: true,
            dataComparisons: data
        });
        kendo.bind($("#container"), viewModel);
    }
})
```

Comment: Hi Gene R, thank you for the hint. So there would be no way to split the json into 2 tables, that then can be distinguished by datasource? I read about deserializing the json, which could do the job, but the way I tried it did not work for me. Would you be able to give me some additional insight to the 2 options you mention? Does it make sense to have 2 or more separate datasources in one view model?

Comment: Thank you for your explanations Gene R.